# How to place divisions between facet grid lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot with `facet_grid` to make a plot for publication.  I'm not sure how the reviewers will react to the standard gray background with white grid lines and so I'm preparing  with and without.  However when I use `opts(panel.background = theme_blank())` the display lacks the between panes discrimination that the standard background gives.  what is the easiest way to add the between pane grid back (not that it was there but it was white against gray) that looks similar to my desired outcome below?

**The Code**

```
ggplot(CO2, aes(conc)) + geom_density() + 
    facet_grid(Type~Treatment) +
    opts(panel.background = theme_blank())
```

**Current Outcome**
[image]

**Desired Outcome**

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how about `last_plot() + theme_bw()`? `opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill=NA, col="black"))` would also do the trick.

Comment: `+opts(panel.margin = unit(0,"in"))` would also work, although I"m not sure how to create the black separating lines between panels.

Comment: @baptise can you give this as an answer and change the ? to a + as it is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I now see this was an either or deal :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should do:

```
last_plot() + theme_bw()
```

or

```
last_plot() + 
   opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"))
```

Since version 0.9.2, `opts` has been [replaced](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) by `theme`:

```
last_plot() + 
   theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"))
```