# Adding legend title and main title in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am trying to use ggplot2 to do the following

1) Change the legend name to  "asset"
2) Add a title to the top
3) Change the border of each panel to a more solid dark line
4) Would like to change the name and color of each panel chart title "corp" etc

This is what I have and I am not sure how to do this Any help is greatly appreciated

```
p <- ggplot(mystratcodes, aes(x=annRisk, y = annRet))
p<- p + facet_grid(. ~ sector) + facet_wrap(~sector)
p<- p + geom_point(size=6, aes(color = (mystratcodes$subsector1))) 
p<-p+scale_x_continuous(labels = percent, name = "Annualized Risk")
p<-p+scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, name = "Annualized Return")
p<-p+ theme( legend.position = "bottom", legend.key = element_rect(colour = "grey"))
p<-p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("UTIL" = "#fdcc8a", "IND" = "#fc8d59", "FIN" =          "#d7301f","ABS" = "#74a9cf", "CMBS" = "#0570b0", "LA" = "#8c96c6", "SOV"= "#88419d", "SUPRA" = "#b3cde3"))
print(p)
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Update: For those who find labels = percent will not work with new ggplot, i,e, if you see `Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'percent' not found` error,  then add this *scales::* bit in front of percent `scales::percent`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) You can change the legend name to "Asset" by putting "Asset" as the first parameter in the `scale_color_manual` function.

```
scale_colour_manual("Asset",values = ...)
```

2) You can do

```
p<-p+labs(title="PUT TITLE HERE")
```

for the title

3) You can add an additional argument to `theme()` to change the background color (which will make a border appear around the box)

```
p<-p+theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA, col="black"))
```

source: [How to place divisions between facet grid lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694452/how-to-place-divisions-between-facet-grid-lines)

You could also try adding `p=p+theme_bw()` earlier in the expression, but that might change too many things.

4) For the grid labels, you have 2 options (well, more, but these are the easiest).  Firstly, you can rename the levels of your data.  If you don't want to do that, you can make a labeller function to pass as an argument in `facet_grid()`.  See the example here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12104207/1362215

For the color of the panel, you can also use `theme()` for that

```
p<-p+theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = 'purple'))#turns boxes purple
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I have one more question. How do I size the points based on a column called capwt. I would like three sizes above 10%, 5-10%, and below 5%. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: You can use `aes(...,size=colvariable)` and `scale_size_identity(values=c(colvariable=1.1*a,varother1=a,varother2=a,...)`.

Comment: You can also use two separate geom_point expressions, where you use the parameter `subset=(mystratcodes$sector=='capwt')` and `subset=(mystratcodes$sector!='capwt')`

See here for more details:  http://mikewhitfield.wordpress.com/2013/11/07/r-graphics-vary-geoms-facets/