# loop plotting from data set

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I have this data set:

```
x <- sample(80)
matrix <- matrix(x, ncol=5, nrow=16)
matrix <- cbind(matrix, c(rep("group1",4), rep("group2",4), rep("group3",4), rep("group4",4)))
colnames(matrix) <- c(letters[1:5], "groups")
df <- as.data.frame(matrix)
```

I would like to be able to plot five boxplots, one for each column from a to e, using a for loop.
I have tried this, but I cannot figure out how to make it work:

```
for(i in df[,1:5]) {
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=groups, y=as.numeric(as.character(i))))
  p +  geom_boxplot()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing here:

```
library(reshape)
ggplot(melt(df, id.vars="groups")) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=groups, y=as.numeric(value))) + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

gives

[image]

and

```
library(reshape)
ggplot(melt(df, id.vars="groups")) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=groups, y=as.numeric(value)), color=variable)
```

gives

[image]

Is any of that close to what you want?

Comment: For example 1: is there a way to keep the group names in each plot?

Comment: @Sergio.pv Yes, in this particular case, use `facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free_x")`

Comment: @Sergio.pv You might want to take a look on the [cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs) for more information.

Comment: is there a way to add a general title to the facet?. I couldn't find an answer in the coockbook.

Comment: @Sergio.pv See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566096) `+ labs(title="test")`